# C: segmentation fault due to not freeing memory in somewhere else. how to free memory

Tags: c

I have a function as Follows:

```
double **E_min;
int *D_K;
double *prob;
char checker[] = "yes";
while(!strcmp(checker,"yes")){
.
.
.
    E[I_indice][t] = ProcurementCost(Q[t+1][I_indice], c, k) + h*fmax(0,I[t])
      + p*fmin(0,I[t])
      + CalculateSigma(d_max, I_indice+Qt_DP, E_min, D_K, prob, t+1, Num_DK);
.
.
.
free(E_min)
free(D_K)
free(prob)
 printf("Do you want to check another forecast? (yes/no)\n");
 scanf("%s", &checker[0]);
} // this is for while loop
```

I have my segmentation fault in **CalculateSigma** function.

here is my calculate sigma function:

```
double CalculateSigma( int D_max, int insideSum, double **Emin,
int *D_K, double *probability, int insideTIME, int num_DK)
  {
    int counter;
    double Sigma = 0;
    for (counter = 0; counter < num_DK; counter++ )
    {   
      Sigma += probability[counter]* Emin[insideSum- D_K[counter]][insideTIME];
    }
    return Sigma;
  }
```

So here is the question.
When I run this program for the first time, it runs completely without any issue. but when it asks that if I want to give another number, it will give me a segmentation fault after getting into **CalculateSigma** function. I think the reason is the three pointers that I have in the function which are : **Emin, D_K, Probability** are not the same as my pointers in the main loop. so I have to free them. but if I free them I get a seg fault from the begining, because they are also somehow related.

So i got completely confused here. can someone tell me what should i do?? 
thanks

Comment: You don't usually get a segmentation fault because of not freeing the memory. It's usually the reverse. Use a debugger.

Comment: You do free E_min, D_K and prob, but there is not allocation -- you should make sure that every free has its corresponding malloc/calloc.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then use the debugger `gdb` & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: It's probably worth checking what the index is here: `Emin[insideSum- D_K[counter]][insideTIME]` as it's a bit convoluted.

Comment: You will need to look at each allocation. This takes particularity when you are using `pointers to pointer` because you have 2 allocations, one for the `pointer` and then a second to allocate for the `data`. Your error is usually due to freeing something that was not allocated to begin with, or freeing something that was not initially allocated with `calloc`, `malloc`, or `realloc`. Just use `gdb` and set a `breakpoint` on a line shortly before the crash. Then `run`. When it crashes, type `backtrace`, then look at the `frame #'s`. Use `frame #`, then `info frame` to see more detail.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Actually I used the valgrind with memory leak check and interestingly with using that The program works flawlessly. only for the first run, I get this valgrind Warning "uninitialised value of size 4" which points to the line I did the sum in Sigma in CalculateSigma function. But I dont know what I didnt initialize :(

Comment: If you are on a 64-bit box, that generally means you have an `int` (or unsigned) value that is used in some way when it does not yet have a value. You must determine whether that is an issue or not. Now it is wise to **always initialize all variables** (even if just to `0`). If you are on a `32-bit` box, then the value at issue could be a `pointer`, `int` or `long` value (all 4-bytes).

Answer (score 0):

There are other issues with the code and/or it is incomplete. But, first things first.

Why do you have ?

```
free(E_min)
free(D_K)
free(prob)
```

if you intend to reuse the variables in the next loop iteration. Also, I don't see where they were first allocated. These are basic questions to be resolved, before proceeding further.

Comment: Ok . yes I did allocate them and I free them because I dont want them to have any conflict in the data. if I free them outside the while loop I get data conflict which means the results are not right.

Comment: Then, shouldn't you reallocate them for the next iteration. Otherwise, you are potentially using freed memory inside calcuateSigma(). Maybe you do, and didn't include all of that code here.